# can't read property inside .subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, undefined

I've a problem with a loop which actually works but give me this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined
```

Here is the code:

```
for (let counter = 0; counter < this.signs.length; counter++) {

      if (this.sign === this.pairs[counter].value) {
        
        this.collectService.getSign(this.sign).subscribe(data => {
          // value X, I try and I export but give me an error
          this.X = data.sign.toString();
          this.changeComponent(this.sign1, this.sign2, this.X);
        });

      }
    }
```

So, one more time, it works but why do I have this error?!

Comment: "it works, but I get an error" <= what?  If there is an error, by definition something is not working.

Comment: Did you declare a variable `X` on your class, or whatever class instance the `collectService` belongs to?

Comment: Yes Taplar, it works!!! But if I check the console.....undefined like I said... In this class, I declare X at the begining as usual. I'm pretty it's due to the .subscribe and I read a couple of things about .map the results but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: There isn't anything in this code snippet that does a console log.  Also if `this.X` blows up because `this` is undefined, then `this.changeComponent` would also blow up.  So given the snippet you have provided, its not clear that that the issue is originating from this code block

Comment: Understand but unfortunately, I have to keep `this.changeComponent(this.sign1, this.sign2, this.X);` inside the loop or `this.x` doesn't take the value, due to the .subscribe...

Comment: I never suggested you move that method out of the loop.  I'm trying to explain to you that you have stated you are seeing issues (undefined in the console) that do not reflect the code you have posted and saying that one thing does not work and another does.  You need to provide a more accurate example of your logic.  Or better yet, create an [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: What is the source line number producing the error, which line _exactly_ is it referring to, and is there any confusion between upper and lower case of `this.X` and `this.x`?

Comment: this is this line: 'this.changeComponent(this.sign1, this.sign2, this.X);'. I export 'this.X' to its child component

Comment: You haven't provided any proof that this error is coming from this code. We are just assuming that the 'X' in the error message is referring to the 'X' in this code. As has been pointed out by @Taplar already you need to provide more.

Comment: I agree that it as good as impossible that calculating the value of `this.X` for use as a parameter would generate the error. As a long shot, try reloading the page with the shift key held down, or testing in another browser, to rule out the browser is not using a cached copy of an earlier version of the code with a bug in it.

Comment: Ok, so in facts, you were right. The undefined was due to the child component who hasn't yet received the value. Just had to put an `<div *ngIf="XTransfer">` in the parent html to wait the value before add the child...